# Type parameter with constrain

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts a `Type` as a parameter:

```
public void DoThings(Type x){...}
```

How can I restrict the passed Type to a known interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generics instead:

```
public void DoThings<X>() where X: IKnown { ... }
```

Otherwise, if you're forced to use a `Type` instance, you'll have to do a runtime check and throw an exception if `x` isn't what is expected.